# Convergence of $\int f_n e^{-f_n}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f, f_n$ are measurable and non-negative on a space of finite measure such that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere.

I want to show that $\int f_n e^{-f_n} dx \to \int f e^{-f}dx$.

I've made a little progress using Egorov's theorem, but have hit a snag.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Since our space has finite measure, by Egorov's theorem there exists a subset $C$ with $\mu (C^c) < \epsilon$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $C$. We can then rewrite our above integral as $\int f_n e^{-f_n} dx = \int_C\left( f_n e^{-f_n} dx\right) + \int_{C^c} \left( f_n e^{-f_n} dx\right)$. By uniform convergence, $\int_C\left( f_n e^{-f_n} dx\right) \to \int_C f e^{-f}dx$.

My attempt to deal with $\int_{C^c} \left( f_n e^{-f_n} dx\right)$ was to bound it above by $\mu(C^c) \sup(f_n e^{-f_n}) < \epsilon \sup(f_n e^{-f_n})$, but this supremum might be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto xe^{-x}$ has a global maximum $\frac{1}{e}$, attained for $x = 1$. Thus, we have:

$$\left|f_n(x)e^{-f_n(x)}\right| \le \frac{1}{e}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Since the measure $\mu$ is finite, $f \equiv \frac{1}{e}$ is an integrable function:

$$\int_X \frac{1}{e}\,d\mu = \frac{1}{e}\cdot\mu(X) < +\infty$$

So by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_n e^{-f_n}\,d\mu = \int_X \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n e^{-f_n}\,d\mu = \int_X f e^{-f}\,d\mu$$